# About Simple Tiled Implementation (sti)

Tags: lua, love2d

so I'm trying to import a tiled map into my game and gives me this error:

libraries/sti/utils.lua:195: Could not open file ../path/to/my/gamesheet/file. Does not exist.

so if you know the answer, let me know

Additional Errors:

```
stack traceback:

[love "boot.lua"]:345: in function <[love "boot.lua"]:341>

[C]: in function 'newImageData'

libraries/sti/utils.lua:195: in function 'fix_transparent_color'

libraries/sti/init.lua:106: in function 'init'

libraries/sti/init.lua:48: in function 'sti'

main.lua:7: in function 'load'

[love "callbacks.lua"]:136: in function <[love "callbacks.lua"]:135>

[C]: in function 'xpcall'

[love "boot.lua"]:361: in function <[love "boot.lua"]:348>

[C]: in function 'xpcall'

[Finished in 77.8s]
```

Comment: try double-checking if you spelled the file name correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I found out hot fix it) Answer:

In the lua file where you exported your tiled project, where it says "image" and it has a directory to the image, replace it with the name of your sprite sheet, but your gonna have to put the sprite sheet in the same directory as the tiled map